# Tensorflow with R-Studio

Tags: tensorflow

Add a second feature (x2) to the input data, so that Y follows the following equation:

Y = 8 + 2x12 + 8x28

Then modify the script accordingly so that your model can train on this input data. Generate a plot of actual Y and predicted Y with X axis ranging from 1 through 101

HERE IS THE CODE

```py
#Import the relevant libraries and initialize the hyper-parameters

library(tensorflow)

learning_rate <- 0.01
training_epochs <- 40

#Set up some fake raw input data
trX <- seq.int(-1, 1, length.out = 101)

#Set up raw output data based on a degree 6 polynomial
num_coeffs <- 6
trY_coeffs <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
trY <- 0
for(i in 1:num_coeffs){
  trY <- trY + trY_coeffs[i] * trX^(i-1)
}

#Add some noise
trY <- trY +rnorm(length(trX), mean = 0, sd=1.3) * 1.5

#Plot the raw data
plot(trX, trY)


X <- tf$placeholder("float")
Y <- tf$placeholder("float")

#Define our polynomial model
model <- function(X, w){
  terms <- list()
  for(i in 0:(num_coeffs-1)){
    term <- tf$multiply(w[i], tf$pow(X, i))
    terms[[i+1]] <- term 
  }
  return(tf$add_n(terms))
}

#Set up the parameter vector to all zero
w <- tf$Variable(tf$zeros(num_coeffs,dtype = 'float'), name="parameters")
y_model <- model(X, w)

#Define the cost function just as before
cost <-  tf$reduce_sum((Y-y_model)^2)
train_op <- tf$train$GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)$minimize(cost)

#Set up the session and run the learning algorithm just as before
sess <- tf$Session()
init <- tf$global_variables_initializer()
sess$run(init)

for(epoch in 1:training_epochs){
  for(i in 1:length(trX)){
    sess$run(train_op, feed_dict=dict(X= trX[i], Y= trY[i]))
  }
}

w_val <- sess$run(w)
print(w_val)

## [1] 0.9349267 1.1665890 4.3310685 4.6033034 3.7153454 5.1843162 #you may not get exactly these values
#Close the session when done
sess$close()

#Plot the result
plot(trX, trY)
trY2 <- 0
for(i in 1:num_coeffs){
  trY2 <- trY2 + w_val[i] * trX^(i-1)
}
lines(trX, trY2, col='red')
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: this code dealing with ONLY one feature Add a second feature (x2) to the input data, so that Y follows the following equation:
Y = 8 + 2x12 + 8x28
Then modify the script accordingly so that your model can train on this input data. Generate a plot of actual Y and predicted Y with X axis ranging from 1 through 101

Comment: send your email and I will send you my work here is mine allifalih@yahoo.com